# Establishing a hot spot

Tags: internet, wireless-networking, hotspot

Can anyone hazard a guess as to the degree of difficulty and the approximate cost of establishing a hot spot at a small lake?

The spot in question is [Lime Lake](http://www.llcoa.org/) and it's a relatively shallow and smallish lake. Approximately 1.5 miles at its longest point to point and about ½ mile across. 
There are bays etc.

Comment: Can you outline approximately the lake's shape and dimensions?

Comment: Its is a relatively shallow and smallish lake' approximately 1.5 miles at its longest point to point and approximately.5 miles accross. There are bays etc.
You can view it on line at llcoa.org Thanks for the info

Answer (score 2):

Well considering a lake isn't going to have any objects in the way to block signal, I would say just buy an extended range N wireless router, make a directional antenna out of two coffee cans (google or youtube the instructions, parts you should be able to find at radio shack and definitely online) and point it out over the lake through a clear window.   Problem solved.  You would be surprised how far radio waves travel over water, you might not even need the external antenna (if it's mounted outside).  If you need to mount it outside closer to the lake I would suggest building a plexiglass enclosure on a pole and running Cat-6 and power through PVC pipe to the location.

Building materials and cabling ~$100
Router ~$100